# Error when publishing CXF WebService to Glassfish4

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, glassfish-4

When publishing a CXF WebService to Glassfish4, I get the following error message:

```
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying 
the app [...] : The lifecycle method [close] must not throw a checked exception. 
Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.annotation.PreDestroy()] on 
annotated element 
[public void org.apache.cxf.rs.security.saml.sso.AbstractSSOSpHandler.close() 
throws java.io.IOException] of type [METHOD]. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Versions:

- apache-cxf-3.0.0-milestone1
- Glassfish 4.0

(I had the same issue with the amq-5.8.0 libs in the CXF-3.0.0 Distribution, which i resolved by just updating to amq-5.9.0 libs)

Any help is appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Fix is delivered within [3.0.0-milestone2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF/fixforversion/12325598).

See Apache JIRA issue [CXF-5529](https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/CXF-5529).